# Fancybox styles not works

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, typescript, fancybox

I have using fancybox on my website to show cookies message

Here is typescript code

```
 import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import "@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css";
import "@fancyapps/fancybox";

    $(function() {
      if ($("#cookie_message")) {
        if (!Cookies.get("cookie_message")) {
          $("#cookie_message").show();
          $("#cookie_message_readmore").on("click", function() {
            $.fancybox.open($("#cookie_message_popup"), { width: 600 });
            Cookies.set("cookie_message", "true", { expires: 7 });
            $("#cookie_message").hide();
          });
        }
      }
    });
```

All okay, it works, but it not using fancybox .css of fancybox.

I imported it like this

import "@fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css";
import "@fancyapps/fancybox";

So it looks like this

[image]

Instead of this

[image]

Comment: Make sure there is no any error for missing fancybox css in console

Comment: Have no errors in console @AwsmeSandy

Comment: are you sure that css is in dist and not in source folder

Comment: Which version is it? is it the latest 3?

Comment: fancybox is in dist.

classes for pop up message is in another folder

But it seems it not using it@Chilll007

Comment: yup - 3.3.0 @AwsmeSandy

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting that this

```
$.fancybox.open($("#cookie_message_popup"), { width: 600 });
```

will render your `#cookie_message_popup` element 600px wide, then no, it does not work that way.

You have to set width for your element using CSS. Think about it - what if user opens your page on device with a width less than 600px? Using CSS, you are free to use any combination of rules, like min-width/max-width, media queries, etc.